# Trying to automate filling input fields of web page a with powershell. But stuck with errors

Tags: windows, powershell, input, automation

I am trying to fill the input fields with powershell but facing these issues.

```
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate("https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx");
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; } 
($ie.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucToolhandler$txtToolInput") |select -first 1).value ="99.99.99.999";
$ie.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucToolhandler$btnAction").click()
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }
```

Output :

> The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set. At line:5 char:1
>   + ($ie.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucToolhand
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound   Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named
>   'click'. At line:6 char:1
>   + $ie.Document.getElementsByName("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucToolhandl
>   ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (click:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: You're using double-quotes so the `$...` strings are trying to expand variables.  Switch to single-quotes (string literal) and your problem is resolved.

Comment: As a point of improvement, I'd suggest the parent div for the input with class `tools_lookup_label`.  That name string looks dynamically generated.

Comment: Confirmed that this works: `($ie.document.getElementsByName('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ucToolhandler$txtToolInput') |select -first 1).value ="99.99.99.999";`